# flutter lacked sufficient permissions to execute

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run flutter on vs code, I download flutter sdk and try o create new flutter project.
the project was created successfully but when I try run the project i get this error on vs code.

```
ProcessException: Found candidates, but lacked sufficient permissions to execute
```

this is output of flutter doctor -v

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 5.4.0-131-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.7.5 on channel stable at /home/elfadil/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c07f788888 (3 weeks ago), 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600
    • Engine revision 0f359063c4
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/elfadil/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/125/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/125/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 72.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 213.7433
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.61.20230301

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • DUB LX1 (mobile) • BVK6R19312001265 • android-arm64  • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • Linux (desktop)  • linux            • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 5.4.0-131-generic
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.64

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can you update the post with an output of `flutter doctor -v` in your question?

Comment: @bingalooo
I update question with flutter doctor -v  output

Comment: seems like you're running on Linux. Have you set the correct permissions for accessing the directory/files?

Comment: @bingalooo no I do not.  how I can set permissions for accessing the directory/files                  yes I am running on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to my comments, it seems like you haven't granted permissions on your directory in Linux.

- `sudo chmod -R u+rw /your/directory/path` (this will enable read and write permissions)
- `sudo chown -R [yourUsername]:[yourUsername] /your/directory/path` (this will make sure that your user has ownership of that directory)
- `sudo usermod -a -G root [yourUsername]` (this will make sure you are under the 'root' usergroup)

This should fix your issues. If there is any issue, please feel free to comment. Else, please mark my answer as accepted!

Comment: thank for your help @bingalooo. but the problem still found after i apply your solution suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have a dual boot Windows / Ubuntu setup and share a data drive for development between the two. If you don't set your NTFS drive to allow execution of files, then you can run into this error as I did. My working `/etc/fstab` entry for the shared drive is:

```
ID=XXXXXXXXX   /media/<YourLoginName>/NVME_DATA   ntfs    defaults,user,rw,exec,fmask=022,dmask=022,gid=1000,uid=1000     0       0
```

Make sure you replace ID=XXXXX with the correct UUID obtained from:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null
```

When you reboot you should be able to execute files on the shared drive. You can test it simply by creating a bash script file and executing it.
WARNING: If you screw your fstab file, you need to go to recovery to fix it. When you change it, test it out with:

```
sudo mount -a
```